# `xskak` executing invalid moves?

Tags: xskak

Move 3 in Game 1 suggests that `xskak` does not flag invalid moves - in this case the white Queen attempting to act as if the black pawn on d4 weren't there, but at least does not execute this particular invalid move. Game 2 however takes things a little further by allowing a non-existent black pawn on e5 to capture the white pawn on d4. Same for skak. Is this intentional?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 21 Feb 2019
\usepackage{xskak}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
\usetextfig

\section{Game 1}
\newchessgame[]
\mainline[style=styleB]{1.e4 e5 2.d4}

\chessboard

\mainline{2... exd4}

\chessboard

\mainline{3.Qd5}

\chessboard

\section{Game 2}
\newchessgame[]
\mainline{1.e4 d5 2.d4}

\chessboard

\mainline{2... exd4}

\chessboard
\end{document}
```

Comment: skak (which  does the parsing in both cases) is not a full chess engine. It does some checking,  but can be fooled

Answer (score 2):

`skak` (which does the parsing in both cases) is not a full chess engine. It does some checking, but can be fooled.